# Laravel Mix and Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, turbolinks, laravel-mix

I am having some problems with turbolinks setup. Here is setup: Laravel Mix - with defaults: bootstrap, jquery,..). And just after bootstrap.js file I have included turbolinks. Everything works until page reload - where I always get error. What am I doing wrong?

ERROR:

```
app.js:1282 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:1282)
    at Object.push../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (vendor.js:105933)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (vendor.js:105934)
    at r.visitCompleted (vendor.js:105934)
    at r.complete (vendor.js:105933)
    at r.<anonymous> (vendor.js:105933)
    at vendor.js:105933
```

LINE with ERROR:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load',function() {
    new SimpleBar(document.getElementsByClassName("js-simplebar")[0]);
    $(".sidebar-toggle").on("click", function() {
        //...
    });
});
```

EDIT
Here are js includes (compiled - Laravel Mix)

```
<head>
<script defer src="/js/manifest.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<scrip`enter code here`t defer src="/js/vendor.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script defer src="/js/app.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
</head>
```

This is my app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
let Turbolinks = require('turbolinks');
Turbolinks.start();

require("./dashboard");
require('./custom/INotifier').run();

require("./theme/bootstrap");
require("./theme/theme");
```

And bootstrap.js (includes jQuery, bootstrap js, axios,...)

```
try {

window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: Add the jquery import on the header, that should be sufficient, and before the turbolink include (or if you have it with laravel mix, before calling the compiled mix script should be jquery there). Otherwise let us know on a snippet how your script is looking with all the imports

Comment: are you getting any error in `catch` of your `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: No, I checked that too.

Comment: have you tried using  jQuery() instead of $() ,if you have other JS libraries included sometimes it solves it.

Comment: Tried that too. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the error you have shown it is written that `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` this error mostly comes when jquery is not defined before the script which is calling it.

Add jquery in the `head` of html, before the `turbolinks` script by downloading the jquery or via cdn that is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using jquery as dependency (npm).

Answer (score 0):

move your `<script defer src="/js/app.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>` above your `vendor.js` and remove `defer` from script tags.
to load jquery before your code

```
<head>
    <script src="/js/manifest.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <scrip src="/js/vendor.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: it's only load order error make sure you dont defer any files and start with your app.js file, and for sure you did `npm run dev` to compile your app.js file

Answer (score 0):

Just try putting JQuery first and then popper js.

```
try {
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
require('bootstrap');

} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

The reason this says so - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js